# How to use Click.start to run one method and click.Stop to run a second method if v-if on said button is satisfied?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a small dashboard that has a series of buttons on it that are present from v-if statements. These v-ifs are fed with an axiox query to my db and sets an array that has basically a bunch canDoWhatever fields(canEdit, canDelete, etc). These are used to check if thist button will show up based on the current state of the database. The issue I am running into is if two users are on the dashboard and the state of the database changes then all users currently on the page do not know the stage changes unless a refresh occurs and the buttons will update with the most recent state.

I am aware I could use SignalR or websocket to keep the state updated and push to the frontend somehow and I will eventually move to that solution but for now I was hoping to manage this by the front end checking for the newest state when the button clicked and if the state has changed (ie, canEdit is now false so that button would have been disabled) then the click method is not actually initiated and the v-if would now be false so that button wouldnt even exist(i could also return some sort of message to for the user to know their last action was not capture).

Comment: I dont see any question

Comment: if the backend can't send a message via websocket to the frontend then the frontend will need to send a message to the backend via API call.  if the user does some action that depends on the database state, send API call to see if the action is valid or not.  the backend figures it out and returns the answer.  wait for the response then have the frontend react accordingly.